# Access speed: local variable vs. array

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, variables, local

Given this example code:

```
struct myStruct1 { int one, two; } first; 
struct myStruct2 { myStruct1 n; int c; } second[255];

// this is a member of a structure in an array of structures! 
register int i = second[2].n.one; 
const int u = second[3].n.one; 

while (1)
{
  // do something with second[1].n.one

  // do something with i

  // do something with u
}
```

Which one is faster?

Is it correct that a local copy of an array index can be copied into a register?

Will it be even faster if the copy is done inside the loop?

Comment: Note that the `register` keyword is deprecated in C++11. And the compiler never had any obligation to enforce `register`, it's just a hint.

Comment: Modern compilers are pretty smart. Putting the value in a variable before entering the loop should be sufficient to ensure it's assigned to a register (assuming a tight loop that actually uses the value heavily, and optimizations are enabled). Often the compiler can even detect that the data doesn't change during the loop (an invariant) and hoist such accesses out of the loop (essentially declaring a temporary variable for you). In general, I suggest looking at the assembly output if you're curious about how something will get compiled -- it doesn't get more exact than that!

Comment: @Cameron with today's processors, even looking at the assembly output won't tell you everything about the timing. The only way to know is to benchmark.

Comment: As an aside, `register` is one of those things that are different in C++ and C. `register` is literally meaningless (and deprecated) in C++; in C its meaning is enforced rigidly [but it doesn't do what you think it does](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/a-common-misconsception-the-register-keyword/).

Comment: @Mark: Hmm, very true. Of course, even benchmarks can be misleading :-)

Answer (score 1):

> Which one is faster?

The only way to know is to measure or *profile*.  You can look at the assembly code to get a hint at which one is faster, but the truth is in the profiling.

> Is it correct that a local copy of an array index can be copied into a register?

A register can hold many things.  The use of registers is controlled by the compiler and the quantity of registers that the processor has available.

The compiler may put values into registers or place them on the stack.  Eventually, values need to go into registers.  Some processors have the ability to copy memory from one location to another without using registers.  Whether or not the compiler uses these features depends on the compiler and the optimization level.

> Will it be even faster if the copy is done inside the loop?

Unnecessary code in a loop slows down the loop.  Compilers may factor out code that isn't changing inside the loop.

Some processors can contain all of the instructions for a loop in their instruction cache; others not.  Again, all this depends on the processor and the compiler optimization settings.

### Micro-optimizations

Your questions fall under the category of *micro-optimizations*.  In general, this group of optimizations usually gains speed in terms of processor instructions.  Unless you iterate over 1.0E+09 times, the optimizations won't gain you significant savings.  With today's processors, were talking an average gain of 100 nanoseconds per instructions (or worst case 1 millisecond).  Unless you have profiled, you don't want to waste your development effort with these optimizations.

### Design, & Coding optimizations

Here is a list of optimizations that will gain more performance benefits than micro-optimizations:

- Removing unwanted requirements.
- Removing unused modules.
- Sharing common modules.
- Using efficient data structures.
- Removing unnecessary work.
- Performing tasks in the background.
- Double buffering.
- Input (blocks), Process (blocks), Output (blocks).
- Reducing function calls, and comparisons.
- Reducing code by simplifying using algebra or Karnough Maps.

Comment: "worst case 1 millisecond" Unless of course the OS needs to page something to the hard drive to make space for your memory...  I had one program that took tons of memory to do a calculation.  The first run took ~30 seconds (after starting), subsequent runs took ~0.3 seconds.